# JavaScript - Console.log return something but with return it shows undefined

Tags: javascript, return, console.log

the problem as the title said : The console.log show the correct value but when I return it and show it with the DOM by adding a paragraph (using jQuery) in the paragraph it shows undefined...

```
console.log(dateTimeUTC(timeZoneStr)); 
// Shows the correct value I wanted

return  dateTimeUTC(timeZoneStr); 
// Shows undefined
```

So what I want to do : A form with html with a simple input text and a submit button, when the submit button is click so it saves the text of the input in a variable using jQuery : `let variable = $('#cityName').val();` (the value should be a city name) because when I've got the city name value I ask the openweathermap API to send me the json and to give the value of the timezone in ms then I need to convert the ms value in hour so for example New York, : timezone: -14400 (`json.timezone  /  60  /  60)` so the result with New york is UTC - 4, then I have a script that convert my UTC thing in  an real date time but that script work so I don't need to explain you... when that function finish it gives me the result like that :

> Tue Aug 13 2019 05:53:39 GMT+0200
>   Not really good for presentation so then I made a function that convert this in a better way :

```
year  =  timeNow.getFullYear();
month  = ('0'+(timeNow.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
day  = ('0'+timeNow.getDate()).slice(-2);
hour  = ('0'+timeNow.getHours()).slice(-2);
minute  = ('0'+timeNow.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
second  = ('0'+timeNow.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
showDateTimeValue  =  day  +  "/"  +  month  +  "/"  +  year  +  " - "  +  hour  +  ":"  +  minute  +  ":"  +  second;
return  showDateTimeValue;
```

Then this return value go where I executed the function so in the function called timeZone and it's there that I've got the console.log working but with return it shows undefined.

Hopefully, I explained well and you'll understand what I'm trying to do, if anyone can give me some help ^_^

**EDIT - FULL CODE :**

Index.html code :

```
<div  class="form-group">
    <label  for="cityName">Displays the local date and time according to the name of the city</label>
    <input  name="cityName"  type="text"  id="cityName"  placeholder="Enter a name of a city..."  class="form-control">
</div>
<br>
<button  type="submit"  id="submit">Submit</button>
<p  class="results"></p>

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
```

main.js code :

```
$(function () {
    $( "#submit" ).click(function() {

    let  city  =  $('#cityName').val();
    cityName  =  city.split(' ').join('+');
    if(cityName  ===  "") {
        $('.results').append("<p>Wrong location.</p>");
    }
    else {
       $('.results').append("<p>The date and time of "  +  city  +  " : "  +  weatherRequest("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="  +  cityName  +  "&units=metric&appid=MyAPIkey") +'</p>'); 
    }
    });
})
```

Function code :

```
/* Function variable */
const messageError = "You didn't enter a valid thing.";
let timeNow = new Date();
let utcOffset = timeNow.getTimezoneOffset();
timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + utcOffset);

// Function that gives the date and hour utc time 
function dateTimeUTC(utc) {
    if(typeof utc === 'string' && utc.length >= 1 && utc[0] === '-' || '0' || '+' || !isNaN(parseFloat(utc[0])))
    {   
        if (utc[0] === '0' && utc.length === 1)
        {   
            let enteredOffset = 0;
            return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
        }
        else if (utc[0] === '+' || !isNaN(parseFloat(utc[0])))
        {
            if (utc.length === 2 && utc[0] === '+')
            {
                // Entered offset
                let enteredOffset = parseFloat(utc[1])*60;
                timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + enteredOffset);
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
            else if (utc.length === 3 && utc[0] === '+')
            {
                // Entered offset
                let enteredOffset = parseFloat(utc[1] + utc[2])*60;
                timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + enteredOffset);
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
            else if (utc.length === 1 && !isNaN(parseFloat(utc[0])))
            {
                // Entered offset
                let enteredOffset = parseFloat(utc[0])*60;
                timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + enteredOffset);
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
            else if (utc.length === 2 && !isNaN(parseFloat(utc[0])))
            {
                // Entered offset
                let enteredOffset = parseFloat(utc[0] + utc[1])*60;
                timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + enteredOffset);
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
            else
            {
                let enteredOffset = 0;
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
        }
        else if (utc[0] === '-')
        {
            if (utc.length === 2 && utc[0] === '-')
            {
                // Entered offset
                let enteredOffset = - parseFloat(utc[1])*60;
                timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + enteredOffset);   
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
            else if (utc.length === 3 && utc[0] === '-')
            {
                // Entered offset
                let enteredOffset = - parseFloat(utc[1] + utc[2])*60;
                timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() + enteredOffset);   
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
            else
            {
                let enteredOffset = 0;
                return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            let enteredOffset = 0;
            return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
        }
    }
    else if (utc === '' || !utc || utc === undefined)
    {
        utc = false;
        let enteredOffset = 0;
        return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
    }
    else
    {
        let enteredOffset = 0;
        return showDateTime(enteredOffset);
    }
}

// Function that shows the date and time correctly (format : dd/mm/yyyy - 00:00:00)
function showDateTime(enteredOffset) {
    year    = timeNow.getFullYear();
    month   = ('0'+(timeNow.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    day     = ('0'+timeNow.getDate()).slice(-2);
    hour    = ('0'+timeNow.getHours()).slice(-2);
    minute  = ('0'+timeNow.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    second  = ('0'+timeNow.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

    showDateTimeValue = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " - " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    timeNow.setMinutes(timeNow.getMinutes() - enteredOffset)

    return showDateTimeValue;
}

// Function which get the shift in seconds between the utc with the API
function timeZone(json) {
    let timeZone = json.timezone / 60 / 60;
    let timeZoneStr = timeZone.toString();
    // console.log("La date et l'heure de " + cityName.split('+').join(' ') + " : " + dateTimeUTC(timeZoneStr));
    console.log(dateTimeUTC(timeZoneStr)); // Shows the correct value I wanted 
    return dateTimeUTC(timeZoneStr); // Shows undefined 
}

// Function that request the openweathermap.org API
function weatherRequest(url) {
    // console.log(url);
    try
    {
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            timeZone(json);
            });
    }
    catch
    {
        console.log("Wrong location.");
    }
}
```

Comment: After `console.log(dateTimeUTC(timeZoneStr));` did you try  
`console.log(timeZoneStr);`? Maybe the string is being changed between log and return

Comment: Yeah I just tested it and here the results : 

    console.log(timeZoneStr); 
    // Output : -4 (in the console of course)

 return (timeZoneStr); 
 // Output : undefined in the paragraph 

And if it can help, here is the code of the execution of the function

    $( "#submit" ).click(function()

 {

 let  city  =  $('#cityName').val();

 cityName  =  city.split(' ').join('+');

 if(cityName  ===  "")

 {

 $('.results').append("<p>Wrong location.</p>");

 }

 else

 {

 $('.results').append("<p>La date et l'heure de "  +  city  +  " : "  +  weatherRequest("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/

Comment: In the code in your comment, which function is the one that returns the dateTimeUTC value? (what is the function's name?)

Comment: Also, can you update your question with this code please just so it's clearer to see?

Comment: Done! Thanks for your interest of helping me.
I'm new to Stack overflow btw ^^

Comment: The issue isn't with function timeZone(json) . It's with function weatherRequest(url) . You aren't returning anything from there. I tried on jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/SharonM/5vn6cut2/58/) but it wouldn't do $.getJSON. If getJSON works for you then just make sure you return something from the weatherRequest function

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack overflow :)

Comment: Thank you and yes $.getJSON doesn't work for you because you need to have an api key from openweathermap. And I tried to return something from weatherRequest like this : 

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    timeZone(json);
    return  "test";
    });

I tried with test, and with the variable I want (showDateTimeValue) and still doesn't work...

Comment: Screen results :
![Screen Results](https://cloud.divlo.fr/public_files/others/Capture74.PNG)

Comment: what does `return  $.getJSON(url, function(json) { timeZone(json); return "test"; }); give you?`

Comment: (I forgot some APIs need keys, thank you for pointing that out)

Comment: Okay now I haven't got undefined but now I have : "[object Object]"
with that code (what you want me to test) 

    function  weatherRequest(url) {
 try
 {
  return  $.getJSON(url, function(json) { timeZone(json); });
 }
 catch
 {
  console.log("Wrong location.");
 }
 }

Comment: If you get [Object object] then do `return JSON.stringify($.getJSON(url, function(json) { timeZone(json); return "test"; }););` It gives the actual string version of the object :)

Comment: And now I've got "{"readyState":1}".
Hmm so weird... I'm pretty new to JavaScript I mean I understand things like hoisting, scope and such but  there ... just why

Answer (score 0):

Alright somebody help me to find out why it was wrong so here is the solution : 
Since we can't know when a request ended or such, you can't return value outside the getJSON, you need to append the things you want directly in the getJSON thingy so yeah here is the code in main.js :

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function()
{
let  city  =  $('#cityName').val();
let  cityName  =  city.split(' ').join('+');
if(cityName  ===  "")
{
    $('.results').append("<p>Wrong location.</p>");
}
else
{
   weatherRequest("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="  +  cityName  +  "&units=metric&appid=MyAPIkey");
}
});
```

Only need to change the function weatherRequest :

```
function  weatherRequest(url) {
// console.log(url);
try
{
    $.getJSON(url, function  callbackSuccess(json) {
let  showDateTimeValue  =  timeZone(json);
let  city  =  json.name;
    $('.results').append("<p>The date and time of "  +  city  +  " : "  +  showDateTimeValue  +  '</p>');
});
}
catch
{
    $('.results').append("<p>Wrong location.</p>");
}
}
```

Hopefully you understood, i'm bad for explaining so yeah...